# build_value n2m relation code generation doesn't work

Tags: dart, flutter

I try to generate my PODO's with [build_value](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart) which works absolutely fine until I hit the use case n:m relation. For example a Speaker can have 1:N Sessions and a session can have 1:N Speaker.

The only way I got it to work was to get rid of the speaker in the session and have 0:N sessions on the speaker. I'm sure I have overlooked something but I do not know what ;D.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Unclear. What is PODO, n:m, 1:N ... ? And can you enough code to reproduce the error ; and add details about the desired effect ?

Comment: Yes, please give more detail :) ... what would you like the classes to look like?